# OpenStreetMap REST Call to find near POIs of specific type

Tags: java, curl

Is there a simple way to get the pois of a type (for example restaurant) that are near me (specific location by latitude/longitude)?
With 
curl -v -G http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=...
i can get them near me but not filtered to the restaurants.
Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: You should add a code sample and show the direction you are going.

Comment: i try to use something like `curl -v -G http://api.openstr
eetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=14.283151783940813,48.28121578394081,14.301138216059
186,48.299202216059186&amenity=restaurant|bar` to get the bar's and restaurant's near a position, but this is not supported. Can you give me an example how to use the rest-api to get locations near a position (in a bounding box) and of a specific type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the osm api. i discovered that what i want is possible with the http://overpass-api.de/api/..